# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error in dot net core web API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net-core, webapi

I am using dot net core Web API.
I have a controller HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAPI.Models;
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(User user)
        {
            return Ok(user);
        }
    }

}
```

The model user is as follows

```
namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run the following jquery code from the front end I get an error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://localhost:7137/Home",
  data: { username: "username" , password: "password"},
  success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  dataType: "application/json"
});
```

I am not getting what mistake I am doing.

**Update:**
I have used `contentType: "application/json"` in the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://localhost:7275/Home",
   type: "POST",
   data: {username:"username",password:"password"},
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      alert("call succeeded");
   },
   failure: function (response) {
      alert("call failed");
   }
});
```

Now its reporting `400 Bad Request`

Comment: So your issue *was* that it was missing `contentType` - please accept the provided answer and *ask a new question*.   Changing the question after someone has answered makes their answer look incorrect and liable to downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused by missing or invalid `Accept` and/or `Content-Type` header, which expected to contain `application/json` value.